# KOMA Script footer line height

Tags: spacing, header-footer, koma-script

How to increase footer text distance from the separator line so that it looks like header?

You can see the distance from footer text to line is less than header....

[image]

Comment: It would be good if you provide a small code example which produces this. Then we would know the specific KOMA class you are using and your settings regarding class, scrpage2 (or fancyhdr, possibly) and everything else involved.

Comment: the example below works

Comment: For background information to this question (in German), see the [KOMA-Script Documentation Project](http://www.komascript.de/node/1552).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[headsepline,footsepline]{scrpage2}
\clearscrheadings
\ihead{Header}
\ifoot{\rule{0pt}{\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox}Footer}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\begin{document}
\mbox{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, and I need to get familiar with `\strutbox`.

Comment: works with scrbook as well

Answer (score 0):

[This is the answer in a similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299863/define-space-between-footsepline-and-footer)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[
    footsepline=0.25pt, % to show the footwidth
]{scrlayer-scrpage}

% shift lines up:
\ModifyLayer[addvoffset=-.6ex]{scrheadings.foot.above.line}
\ModifyLayer[addvoffset=-.6ex]{plain.scrheadings.foot.above.line}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```