# Define space between footsepline and footer

Tags: header-footer, rules

How to push footer text (red rectangle) down from footsepline (green rectangle)? Position of the footer (as a whole) on the page is not relevant.

[image: footsepline in green and footer text number in red box]

MWE: ( `\setlength\footheight{1.5\baselineskip}` is just pushing both boxes up)

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[
    footsepline=0.25pt, % to show the footwidth
]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\setlength\footheight{1.5\baselineskip}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is `footsepline`?

Comment: @Bernard A line above the footer text, assuming the line has been activated with a switch `footsepline = true` in `scrbook` class for an instance. Does that make sense? Couldn't find an existing answer :/

Comment: That is specific to `komascript`, I guess, unless you'respeaking of the short line between text and `footnotes`.

Comment: @Bernard Added an image, hopefully that makes things clear.

Comment: I've just looked at the documentation. Maybe  `\setlength\footheight{1.25\baselineskip}` (or `1.5`) would produce what you want.

Comment: @Bernard Not working. Footheight is not relevant, it seems the footer text is pushed up to separation line and the remaining height is placed below.

Comment: Could you post a (non-)working minimal example?

Comment: @Bernard Solved with help of this [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19859/koma-script-footer-line-height/19861#19861). Inserting rule in footer, with 0pt width and thickness as height makes it work: `\rule{0pt}{<desired height>}`

Comment: Yes, it solves the problem. But you you shouldn't  have to resort to such tricks, in my opinion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Either you shift the layers with lines up

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[
    footsepline=0.25pt, % to show the footwidth
]{scrlayer-scrpage}

% shift lines up:
\ModifyLayer[addvoffset=-.6ex]{scrheadings.foot.above.line}
\ModifyLayer[addvoffset=-.6ex]{plain.scrheadings.foot.above.line}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

or the layers with the foot down

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[
    footsepline=0.25pt, % to show the footwidth
]{scrlayer-scrpage}

% shift foot down
\ModifyLayer[addvoffset=.6ex]{scrheadings.foot.odd}
\ModifyLayer[addvoffset=.6ex]{scrheadings.foot.even}
\ModifyLayer[addvoffset=.6ex]{scrheadings.foot.oneside}
\ModifyLayer[addvoffset=.6ex]{plain.scrheadings.foot.odd}
\ModifyLayer[addvoffset=.6ex]{plain.scrheadings.foot.even}
\ModifyLayer[addvoffset=.6ex]{plain.scrheadings.foot.oneside}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `scrheadings.foot.odd` etc. aren't mentioned in the manual. Did you learn about them by reading the code, and if so, where in the code are they mentioned? And for the record, what do `scrheadings.foot.odd`, `scrheadings.foot.even`, and `scrheadings.foot.oneside` correspond to?

Comment: Never mind, I see it in Table 18.1 on pg 455.